# Neural Network seems to work fine until used for processing data (all of the results are practically the same)

Tags: c++, neural-network

I have recently implemented a typical 3 layer neural network (input -> hidden -> output) and I'm using the sigmoid function for activation. So far, the host program has 3 modes:

1. Creation, which seems to work fine. It creates a network with a specified number of input, hidden and output neurons, initializes the weights to either random values or zero.
2. Training, which loads a dataset, computes the output of the network then backpropagates the error and updates the weights. As far as I can tell, this works ok. The weights change, but not extremely, after training on the dataset.
3. Processing, which seems to work ok. However, the data output for the dataset which was used for training, or any other dataset for that matter is very bad. It's usually either just a continuuous stream of 1's, with an occasional 0.999999 or every output value for every input is 0.9999 with the last digits being different between inputs. As far as I could tell there was no correlation between those last 2 digits and what was supposed to be outputed.

How should I go about figuring out what's not working right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a set of parameters (number of neurons, learning rate, number of iterations for training) that works well for classifying previously unseen data. People often achieve this by separating their data into three groups: training, validation and testing.

Whatever you decide to do, just remember that it really doesn't make sense to be testing on the same data with which you trained, because any classifcation method close to reasonable should be getting everything 100% right under such a setup.

Comment: I mostly agree with you. What do you mean by number of iterations for training? Yes I know testing on the data on which I trained doesn't make sense, but if it can't even do that, how well do you think it will perform on previously unseen data (It's got the same accuracy rate, so completely useless)? What I mean to say is that I think the problem lies somewhere else other than the architecture of the network, I believe it lies somewhere in my code.